# How can I kill/separate a Deity from the Prime Material Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, religions-and-deities

I need my BBEG to kill/separate a god from the material plane/everything. The PCs are helping NPCs save their god, and while I think they could probably do it, I do wanna know what to do if they don’t or if they take too long (seeing as the NPCs lose their divine powers).

The deity isn’t on the prime material plane, but she has a source of power/influence that the BBEG is trying to destroy. Is there an established way to either trap the god somewhere so she can no longer contact/influence the material plane, or just straight up kill her?

(This is my/our first time playing D&D, so I apologize if I’m not making much sense. Thanks!)

Comment: Which setting? Forgotten Realms, for example, have a long history of deities being killed.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 15):

## Through DM magic

What you are suggesting is entirely in the realm of DM storytelling. There's no mechanics in the game for killing or trapping gods.

In the more of various D&D settings, there have been similar events:
**Tharizdun** is a god of destruction that was imprisoned in a demi-plane to keep it from destroying existence.

The Kobold god **Kurtulmak** was imprisoned in a maze by the Gnome god **Garl Glittergold**.

**The Dead Three** were mortals who convinced the god of death **Jergal** to step down and to give them their power. They were later killed during the Time of Troubles.

One of the biggest dead god events would be the death of **Mystra**, who was assassinated and which caused the Spellplague to happen because the Weave is connected to Mystra.

**Karsus** was a mortal who thought he had to save his realm by taking on the mantle of a god, and he cast a massive spell that killed the goddess of magic (she never gets a break) to gain her power. This ended up causing magic to go haywire, because he had no idea how to keep the Weave running and he drastically underestimated how much a god does. The end of his country from the resulting magical failures is known as Karsus's Folly. That said, Mystra has since made magic as powerful as that impossible as far as most mortals know.

In other words... it is possible to trap or kill a god, but there are no defined mechanics and it's essentially DM storytelling. Come up with a reason that sounds plausible to you and your players and nobody will complain that "that is not how it works".

Comment: Added it, @illustro. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

#### Kill all the deity's followers

As a DM, you can always invent some maguffin to explain how a deity can be killed. Commonly, this is some cataclysmic event, artifact, ritual, monster, weakness, or another deity; some easily-grasped villain, object or event that the player characters can stop, capture, kill, or interrupt.

However, according to the D&D 5e *Dungeon Master's Guide* p.11, "Divine Rank", a deity can also effectively die if they lose all of their worshipers, or nearly all. If everyone on Oerth stopped believing in Pelor, or someone killed nearly everyone who believes in Pelor, then for all intents and purposes Pelor would be dead.

It's like a company who goes out of business: technically the corporation may still exist, but in practice it's unable to serve any customers.

Comment: *The International Federation of Murderhobos (Local 237) would like to thank you for this ringing endorsement of our core competency* ... 8^D